Get-PnPSiteTemplate: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden
I want to copy one site collection from one tenant to another, so on the source tenant, I created this App Registering and I grant it full control on SharePoint:-

And I define to use secret for the authentication:-

Then I run this command:-
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://****.sharepoint.com/sites/****Integration" -ClientId "***" -ClientSecret "ptv**"

Connecting with Client Secret uses legacy authentication and provides limited functionality. We can for instance not execute requests towards the Microsoft Graph, which limits cmdlets related to
 Microsoft Teams, Microsoft Planner, Microsoft Flow and Microsoft 365 Groups. You can hide this warning by using Connect-PnPOnline [your parameters] -WarningAction Ignore

then i got this error, when i tried to Get the site template:-
Get-PnPSiteTemplate -Out "Integration.xml"
Get-PnPSiteTemplate: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Any advice? i remember i did this operation 1 year ago and it worked well.
Thanks

Access denied or 403 Forbidden is the expected result if you are using a registered Entra ID application with a client secret. Due to security reinforcement, only certificate will work.

FAQ: Can I use other means besides certificates for realizing app-only access for my Azure AD app?
No, all other options are blocked by SharePoint Online and will result
in an Access Denied message.

Source: Granting access via Azure AD App-Only
Try to generate a new certificate for your application with application permissions Sites.FullControl.All and use it to connect to SharePoint:
$password = (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText 'myprivatekeypassword' -Force)
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "contoso.sharepoint.com" -ClientId 6c5c98c7-e05a-4a0f-bcfa-0cfc65aa1f28 -CertificatePath 'c:\mycertificate.pfx' -CertificatePassword $password  -Tenant 'contoso.onmicrosoft.com'

Reference: Connect-PnPOnline


ok thanks a lot , but looks too much as i will need to do this on the source and on the destination, can we do this using the login user credentials instead?

No other option, except a certificate.
